# How to increase horizontalfieldmanager height dynamically in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I have added RichTextField to HorizontalFieldManager, and I also set Background bitmap to HorizontalFieldmanager. If the richtextfield text increases the horizontalfield manager height, how can I increase height dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HorizontalFieldManager by default will increase its size to show whatever fields you have placed inside of it.

If this is not the case then it sounds like you have overridden this behavior. Without seeing code I can only guess, E.g. by using a static height or width in the sublayout.